# In javascript, how can I transform an email address into a valid DOM id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'd like to take an email address and convert it to a [valid DOM id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1093087) so that it can be used to dynamically build an HTML element with jQuery.

For example:

- Given: `some.user@example.com`
- Returns: `some-user-at-example-com`
- For: `$('<div />').attr('id, 'some-user-at-example-com');`

Somewhat like the Rails parameterize method. What's a clean, simple way to do this?

Comment: Why storing an email as ID value? Why don't you use `data-*` attributes?

Comment: Why not use an array index or key and store your data however you want into a JavaScript var?

Comment: As to why I want an email as an ID, I'm building a small dynamic interface with jQuery and it provides a convenient handle for selecting various children of the parent element to which it will be applied. I'm not promoting this as a general practice, but it serves my purposes here.

Comment: Put the email address in an object and assign a value, unique id to the element. Then use one to lookup the other as required. Does not require any munging of the email address or invalid characters in the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that output for that input exactly, you could use a regular expression or three:

```
var id = email.replace(/@/g, ' at ').replace(/[^a-z0-9-]+/gi, '-')
              .replace(/^-|-$/g, '');
```

First, we replace the at signs with "at" (with leading and trailing spaces). Then we replace any sequence of non-alphanumeric characters with a dash.

Take note, however, that multiple email addresses can become the same ID. For example, `john.doe@example.com` and `john-doe@example.com` both become `john-doe-at-example-com`. You should not use these identifiers for IDs, as they are not unique.

Comment: Collisions like that aren't a concern. This almost works as hoped, though I tried it on one of the "valid email addresses" provided by @elclanrs, `"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com`, and it produced: `-very-VERY-very-at-very-unusual-at-strange-example-com`.

Comment: @klenwell: Oh, I forgot about that corner case. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Regex and `replace` should do, but you really should consider if this approach is worth doing given that there are sooo many potential valid email addresses.

```
'some.user@example.com'.replace(/[.@]/g ,'-')
```

From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) on "valid email addresses":

```
niceandsimple@example.com
very.common@example.com
a.little.lengthy.but.fine@dept.example.com
disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com
user@[IPv6:2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0]
"much.more unusual"@example.com
"very.unusual.@.unusual.com"@example.com
"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com
postbox@com (top-level domains are valid hostnames)
admin@mailserver1 (local domain name with no TLD)
!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org
"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
" "@example.org (space between the quotes)
```